# minimize an anonymous function via fminunc with two inputs vectors (matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function, minimization

You can minimize a function using `fminunc` like this:

```
x = linspace(-2,2,1000);
f0      = -x.^2;
ftest1  = @(a) a(1)*exp(-a(2)*x.^2);
fmin1   = @(a) trapz(x,(ftest1(a) - f0).^2);

[a1,fval] = fminunc(fmin1,rand(1,2));
plot(x,f0,x,ftest1(a1));
```

Is there a similar way to do this if you'd like to minimize with respect to two different (vector) variables?:

```
x = linspace(-2,2,1000);
f0      = -x.^2;
ftest2  = @(a,b) a(1)*exp(-b(1)*x.^2) + a(2)*exp(-b(2)*x.^2);
fmin2   = @(a,b) trapz(x,(ftest2(a,b) - f0).^2);
%[a2,b2,fval] = fminunc(...
```

Comment: You need to know the length of `a` and  `b`... call it `n`... after that it's pretty simple:

Comment: @transversalitycondition if you have a solution then post it.

Comment: According to documentation "A scalar objective function file accepts one input, say x, and returns one scalar output, say f". Why not pack both variables in a 1x4 vector?

Comment: Good find in the doc... that clears it up anyway.  I was hoping to avoid this since its not quite as clean in the more complicated example.